# searching mechanism of tree of collections

Tags: java, collections, comparable

```
> classcast exception is occur in output
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: collections1.Emp        cannot be cast to java.lang.Comparable
    at java.util.TreeMap.compare(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.TreeMap.put(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.TreeSet.add(Unknown Source)
    at collections1.Empts.main(Empts.java:57)
```

> I have implemented the comparable in test class then why above exception occurred. comparable and comparator interfaces are implemented for sorting by names,jobs,salary. tree collections are used for adding names,jobs,salary.
>
> I have not mention emp class but in output it is showing that collections.emp cannot be casted.

```
  package collections1;
import java.util.*;
class Test implements Comparable
{
    String name,job;
    int salary;
    @Override
    public int compareTo(Object o) {
        Test e=(Test)o;
        return this.name.compareTo(e.name);
    }
    public Test(String n,String j,int s)
    {
           name=n;
           job=j;
            salary=s;
    }
    public void display()
    {
        System.out.println(name+"\t"+job+"\t"+salary);
    }
}


class Jobcomparator implements Comparator
{

    @Override
    public int compare(Object o, Object p) 
    {
        Test e1=(Test)o;
        Test e2=(Test)p;
        return e1.job.compareTo(e2.job);
    }

}

class Salarycomparator implements Comparator
{

    @Override
    public int compare(Object o, Object p) 
    {
        Test e1=(Test)o;
        Test e2=(Test)p;
        return e1.salary-e2.salary;
    }

}
public class Empts
{

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
    
    TreeSet set=new TreeSet();
    set.add(new Emp("tanya","student",5000));
    set.add(new Emp("saloni","teacher",60000));
    set.add(new Emp("vaishnavi","manager",90000));
    System.out.println("set elements in ascending order of name");
    display(set.iterator());

    TreeSet js=new TreeSet(new Jobcomparator());
    js.addAll(set);
    System.out.println("set elements in ascending order of job");
    display(js.iterator());

    TreeSet s=new TreeSet(new Salarycomparator());
    s.addAll(set);
    System.out.println("set elements in ascending order of salary");
    display(s.iterator());

    }

    private static void display(Iterator itr)
    { 
            while(itr.hasNext())
            {
                Test e=(Test)itr.next();
                e.display();
            }
    } 

}
```

Comment: You didn't show the implementation of Emp. I'm assuming it does not implement Comparable. Besides, you are using raw types, which is not recommended.

Comment: @Eran thanku. But why should I implement emp there is no use of it I have implemented test class

Comment: Your first TreeSet (`TreeSet set=new TreeSet();`) will rely on the elements you put in it to implement Comparable, since you didn't supply a Comparator. You are putting Emp elements in that set, not Test elements, so Emp must implement Comparable.

Comment: @Eran     I got it.. Thanku so much!!!